# Can't connect to the DB2 database on localhost, using DBeaver 3.1.1

Tags: db2

**Solved: I was connecting to the wrong port, according to `/etc/services | grep db2`**

I have a DB2 Express C v.10.5 database running on localhost, but simply I can't connect to it.

Translation of the error message below:
"*java.net.ConnectException: An error occured when opening the socket to the server ... on port 50000 with message: Connection refused*"
[image: Connection error dialog]

Driver properties: [image: driver properties]

I am using *DBeaver 3.1.1, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit.*

Can somebody please help?  :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure db2 is started:

```
#> db2 connect to <db>
```

If that's not ok, use db2start. Next what port is db2 listening to?

```
#> cat /etc/services | grep db2
```

If it's not 50000 change your connections string in DBeaver. Next try to telnet to the port (assuming it is 50000):

```
#> telnet localhost 50000
```

If that's fine (saying something like Escape charater is ^]), check if DB2COMM is set:

```
#> db2set | grep DB2COMM
```

It should say DB2COMM=TCPIP

Is it a firewall issue? Check with:

```
#> sudo iptables -L
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :) Instance of that DB was currently running on port 50001, not 50000